# Where can I see Item data in GA4?

Tags: e-commerce, google-tag-manager

I am testing Ecommerce Item data in GA4. On debug view, I see the data was sent to GA4 but I can't see location_id, affiliation, index variables or its data in GA4 at all. Could anyone advise?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to have those available in reports, you will need to create custom dimensions in the Configure >> Customer Definitions panel. From here, you can create the dimensions by selecting the parameter and then assigning it a better name (i.e. item_category to Item Category).

As long as the data is being passed to GA4 now, you should be able to create those. If it is new data, you will need to capture it first, pass it to a parameter, then create the dimension.